# Is a friends feature required for developing a chat app with phone authentication

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've seen a lot of chat application examples on youtube, google and github on how to make chat applications. I have used the same logic and made an application but not able to recieve messaged from the other user. Like it's getting saved in the database but not able to retrieve it. It just striked my mind that almost all of the examples i saw have this feature of sending and accepting friend request. is that compulsory for making an app using firebase. Like can that be the reason as to why i'm not able to retrieve the messages sent by the other user?

Please help me out i've been stuck at this point for months now

If you want to see how i retrieve messages... Here's the code for it

```
private void fetchMessages() {
    rootRef.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messageList);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, messagesList);
            String message = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
            message = dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue().toString();
//                Log.d("TAG",message );
            messagesList.add(message);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

Database

```
{
"Messages" : {
"8hbPUUlw39OABqmqSJ63BAHFjan2" : {
  "OcAXeb0KAzfkXSNXyDddAOpBdyh1" : {
    "-L7tuwuIKTkaskiJxU0c" : {
      "message" : "Hii",
      "seen" : false,
      "time" : 1521390178351,
      "type" : "text"
    },
    "-L7u3Z8fnmwKpyvf-0Qy" : {
      "message" : "hi",
      "seen" : false,
      "time" : 1521392698442,
      "type" : "text"
    },
    "-L7u3oT5nGW1181Hfh0g" : {
      "message" : "Ufff",
      "seen" : false,
      "time" : 1521392765184,
      "type" : "text"
    },
    "-L7uFBt6kECyA7FvUmhm" : {
      "message" : "hhfjgivugihihjihycvyuhuhuhi",
      "seen" : false,
      "time" : 1521395748801,
      "type" : "text"
    }
  }
},
"OcAXeb0KAzfkXSNXyDddAOpBdyh1" : {
  "8hbPUUlw39OABqmqSJ63BAHFjan2" : {
    "-L7tuwuIKTkaskiJxU0c" : {
      "message" : "Hii",
      "seen" : false,
      "time" : 1521390178351,
      "type" : "text"
    },
    "-L7u3Z8fnmwKpyvf-0Qy" : {
      "message" : "hi",
      "seen" : false,
      "time" : 1521392698442,
      "type" : "text"
    },
    "-L7u3oT5nGW1181Hfh0g" : {
      "message" : "Ufff",
      "seen" : false,
      "time" : 1521392765184,
      "type" : "text"
    },
    "-L7uFBt6kECyA7FvUmhm" : {
      "message" : "hhfjgivugihihjihycvyuhuhuhi",
      "seen" : false,
      "time" : 1521395748801,
      "type" : "text"
    }
  },
  "OcAXeb0KAzfkXSNXyDddAOpBdyh1" : {
    "-L7u8PbR_UNNxQT93sEt" : {
      "message" : "Hi",
      "seen" : false,
      "time" : 1521393970012,
      "type" : "text"
    }
  }
}
},
"Users" : {
"8hbPUUlw39OABqmqSJ63BAHFjan2" : {
  "Image" : "default",
  "Name" : "Akash",
  "Status" : "Hey",
  "Thumb_image" : "default",
  "Unique" : "8hbPUUlw39OABqmqSJ63BAHFjan2"
},
"OcAXeb0KAzfkXSNXyDddAOpBdyh1" : {
  "Image" : "default",
  "Name" : "Sh",
  "Status" : "Hey",
  "Thumb_image" : "default",
  "Unique" : "OcAXeb0KAzfkXSNXyDddAOpBdyh1"
}
}
}
```

All users activity

```
atabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("Users");

    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.usersList);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, al);
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                unique = ds.child("Unique").getValue().toString();
                name = ds.child("Name").getValue().toString();
                list_user_id = ds.getKey();


                al.add(name);



            }
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please Check Your Internet Connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);

     usersList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            UserDetails.chatWith = al.get(position);
            String user_id = al.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Chat.class);
            intent.putExtra("visit_user_id",unique);
            intent.putExtra("user_name",name);
            startActivity(intent);
            Log.d("TAG",unique);
        }
    });
    return rootView;
```

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: Then y am i not able to retrieve? even in the logcat only my messages r retrieved. the messages sent by the other user isn't showed

Comment: The first thing to do is to stop ignoring errors: `public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError,toException(); }`. This may uncover valuable information about why your app isn't working.

Comment: Next up try running the code under a debugger. Does your `onChildAdded` get triggered? If so, does `message` get the value you'd expect it to have?

Comment: A third step is to move the code creating the adapter out of `onChildAdded`. Right now you're creating a new adapter for each message, which means you're going to be showing at most one message.

Comment: When i debug the app... the data under variables is showing that everything is null=null... when new child is added to database it does show in the listview of my phone... but if the other user sends a message im not able to retrieve that,,, but again i send a message its getting retrieved. but both the users sending message is getting stored in database

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to stop ignoring errors:

```
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { 
  throw databaseError,toException(); 
}
```

This may uncover valuable information about why your app isn't working.

Next up try running the code under a debugger. Does your `onChildAdded` get triggered? If so, does message get the value you'd expect it to have?

A third step is to move the code creating the adapter out of `onChildAdded`. Right now you're creating a new adapter for each message, which means you're going to be showing at most one message.

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messageList);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, messagesList);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

rootRef.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        String message = dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue().toString();
        messagesList.add(message);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Nope still the same... i just noticed one more thing that is... although i have coded for the users to go to different chat rooms each when u click on a particular user, they are not... even in the database the messages are getting stored according to the message ids... but while retrieving when i click on a particaular user the same messages i send to that user i can read in someone elses message room also.... so maybe altho the data is getting stored separately in db... its retrieving only one part of data... also i hav updated my question ... can u find if its not working because of that